# Looping Through Arrays VBA

Tags: excel, vba

all! I do some VBA programming on the side for some coworkers at work. The current request is to generate a list of names for a ticket raffle. I would generate a name x amount of times, for how many tickets they have bought, and add a unique identifier on the end.

[image]

For example, if Pikachu bought 40 tickets, the code would generate "Pikachu1", "Pikachu2", etc. The end result would look like this:

> Pikachu1
> Pikachu2
> .
> .
> .
> Pikachu40
> Bulbasaur1
> Bulbasaur2
> Bulbasaur3
> .
> .
> .
> Bulbasaur20

I am having trouble with loops and arrays. Currently I have an array for the names and an array for the numbers of tickets. I'm thinking I loop through the array of names, generate the name numberOfTickets time, add the unique identifier, and so on and so forth.

Here is my code right now:

```
Sub raffleTickets()

Dim totalRaffleTickets As Variant
Dim nNames As Variant
Dim y As Integer

totalRaffleTickets = Range("$I5:$I135").Value
nNames = Range("$A5:$A135").Value

For y = LBound(nNames) To UBound(nNames)
        ...
Next y


End Sub
```

Previously I hard coded it so I got the name from the cell and then printed it x many of times, but I want to figure out how to do this without brute force.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use a nested loop to generate the list
- Write the output to a new worksheet (modify as needed)

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [ReDim statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/redim-statement?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vblr6.chm1008999)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

> [Range.Resize property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.resize?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144187)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub raffleTickets()
    Dim totalRaffleTickets As Variant
    Dim nNames As Variant
    Dim y As Long, x As Long, arrRes, iR As Long, iTotal As Long
    totalRaffleTickets = Range("$I5:$I135").Value
    nNames = Range("$A5:$A135").Value
    ' get the total tickets
    iTotal = Application.Sum(Range("$I5:$I135"))
    ReDim arrRes(1 To iTotal, 0)
    iR = 0
    ' loop throught names
    For y = LBound(nNames) To UBound(nNames)
        If totalRaffleTickets(y, 1) > 0 Then
            For x = 1 To totalRaffleTickets(y, 1)
                ' populate array
                iR = iR + 1
                arrRes(iR, 0) = nNames(y, 1) & CStr(x)
            Next x
        End If
    Next y
    ' write output to a new sheet
    Sheets.Add
    Range("A1").Resize(iR, 1) = arrRes
End Sub
```

Comment: Oh my goodness! This works! Thanks so much! I think I was blocked on the "For x = 1 to totalRaffleTickets..." part.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code - you have to adjust the address of rgData - and the target range for the output.

```vb
Public Sub raffleTickets()

Dim rgData As Range
Set rgData = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:B3")


Dim arrConfig As Variant
arrConfig = rgData.Value


Dim arrResult As Variant
ReDim arrResult(1 To Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(rgData.Columns(2)), 1 To 1)


Dim i As Long, j As Long, z As Long

For i = 1 To UBound(arrConfig, 1)
    For j = 1 To arrConfig(i, 2)
        z = z + 1
        arrResult(z, 1) = arrConfig(i, 1) & j
    Next
Next

ActiveSheet.Range("D1").Resize(UBound(arrResult)).Value = arrResult

End Sub
```